# react app express js the proper way to establish session for user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, cookies, google-oauth

I am creating react app with node/express/mongodb backend. I tried to use passport.js with Google Strategy, but I don't want to be redirected. I found another way to authorize users.

On my frontend app:

npm install --save react-google-login

insert component in the code:

```
<GoogleLogin
              clientId="my google client id"
              buttonText="Login"
              onSuccess={this.props.responseGoogle}
              onFailure={this.props.responseGoogle}
            />
```

create callback function:

```
responseGoogle(response) {
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    axios.post('/api/v1/tokensignin', { tokenId: response.tokenId }, headers)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Backend:

npm install body-parser

npm install --save cookie-session

npm install --save google-id-token-verifier

Receive post request on backend:

```
app.post('/api/v1/tokensignin', (req, res) => {
    const tokenId = req.body.tokenId;
    const clientId = keys.googleClientID;
    verifier.verify(tokenId, clientId, (err, tokenInfo) => {
      if (!err && tokenInfo.aud === clientId) {
        User.findOne({ googleId: tokenInfo.sub }).then((existingUser) => {
          if (existingUser) {
            if (!req.session.user) {
              req.session.user_id = {};
            }
            req.session.user_id = existingUser.id;
          } else {
            new User({ googleId: tokenInfo.sub })
              .save()
              .then(user => { 
                if(!req.session.user) {
                  req.session.user_id = {};
                }
                req.session.user_id = user.id; 
              });
          }
          res.sendStatus(200);
        });

      } else {
        console.log('ERROR: ', err);
        res.status(500).send('TokenId not verified');
      }
    });
  });
```

Have middlewares in index.js:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
  cookieSession({
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: [keys.cookieKey]
  })
);
```

question is is this established user session secured?

Will I always have access to req.session.user_id in all requests on the backend side?  is there better way to do the same?

Comment: You can probably add a custom middleware to do the validation on every request, so that you don't have to do it in all your endpoints.

Comment: I created middleware. It is working.